# Simple jQuery AJAX JSON Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am attempting to post user data to a php script and return the results to be displayed in an element. All data is being sent the using json method..

Everything is fine up until the response. When trying to append the response to an element i get undefined, however a simple console log shows the correct results. The php side of the house is fine, data is being returned with a json encoded array.

Here is my jquery.

```
$('#roll').click(function(){
     $.ajax({ url: 'roll.php',
             data: {'region' : '46'},
             dataType: 'json',
             type: 'post',
             success: function(data){
                $('#result').append('<span>' + data + '</span>');
                console.log(data);
            }
    });

    return false;

})
```

PHP

```
$data = array('roll' => $roll, 'status' => $status);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Side note: Although I am proficient with javascript & jquery, I haven't really ever had the need to work with ajax before, so this is my first so called attempt at it. If there is a better way to do things, please let me know.

Comment: yes, it returned undefined aswell. Additionally I would like to be able to select the particular individual result for the json array.

Comment: What is returned exactly in the `console.log`?

Comment: If you're encoding a PHP array, then `data` will be a Javascript array or object. String concatenation isn't going to return anything useful, you need to extract the particular elements that you want from the array.

Comment: can you provide me with an example please.

Comment: If you post what `console.log(data)` shows, and tell us which element you want to display, we can show you how to do it.

Comment: Use a breakpoint or `console.log()` to see exactly what `data` is in your success handler.  You probably need to look into the data structure to get something out of it rather than just use the whole thing.  The debugger should be your friend here.  Set a breakpoint an examine what data you have.  If you don't know how to do that, learn - it will save you oodles of time and frustration.

Comment: [Log] Object (fb.js, line 10)
roll: 49.69
status: "win"
__proto__: Object is my console log

Comment: Ive added my php code that handles the array

Comment: I want to display the roll var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#result').append('<span>' + data.roll + '</span>');
```

Comment: does `console.log(data[0].status);` log anything useful?

Comment: Ya these were blind stabs. I don't work with PHP, I'm a .NET guy so its hard for me to tell how your response is getting returned. Maybe try `data.roll` as it could be returning just an object not an array containing objects.